# I got a BootstrapMethodError after upgrading okhttp

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

After upgrading okhttp library in my android app, I got a BootstrapMethodError on initialization.

```
  java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #4 bootstrap method
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.immutableList(Util.java:234)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.java:124)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:449)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your source compatibility to Java 8 in the build.gradle and the problem is gone:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```